how is my avocado?

I need help, please. I have doubts about my avocado, I think it is very big and I don't know if that is bad, I have heard that in several cases they cut them so that they branch, but in my case, will it be okay?
I think my avocado is very long, it measures about 1.60m. If I cut it, in which part should I do it? Or is it not necessary to do so? I am thinking about transplanting my avocado to a field that I have because I no longer have space in my house. I was thinking about transplanting it the other month, but with that I had doubts if it would be a good idea or if my avocado is in condition to transplant it.
You can see in the image that my avocado trunk is very thin and I don't know if that is good or bad, if I should wait or intervene. I don't know what to do with my avocado so that it continues to grow well, so that I can have good fruit from it in the future.

You should transplant it as soon as you can.  It is a tree, so it will not look like a bush.  When you plant it, ensure that you have a good strong stake next to it and tie the plant to it.

For stakes, you can visit a garden centre, or find a length of wood, plastic rod or metal rod.
For tying - you find suitable ties at a garden centre, or use a non-abrasive twine, or a length of a strip of cloth or old stockings.  It should not be too tight, the plant should be able to move.  You may need two or three ties.


Thank you very much for answering. Then I can leave my avocado in the field without having to cut something. Then I will transplant my avocado and obviously, as you said, I leave it a support stake with a string, with 1 or more ties so that it grows well and is not so tight. I will surely do it these days about the avocado transplant. Again, thank you very much

I disagree that an avo will not look like a bush.  Correctly pruned, most commercial avos look like bushes.   I do agree that the pot is to small for the avo.

In general, avocados - left to their own devices will grow very tall (think 10-20 meters tall).
In order to encourage them to grow outwards and not up, you need to cut off the main branch.  Typically that would be done  just above a node - ie just above where leaves come out) between 1m and 1.6m above the ground - generally closer to 1m so you will be able to reach the fruit easily.      When making the cut it is typical to do it at an angle (say 30-45 degrees). Its drastic, but probably something you need to do here.
That avo is definitely ready to be moved from the pot - although I would leave some time between transplanting it and cutting off the top as both are very stressful for the plant.
